Ubuntu crashed running in VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host
It showing a screen like this:

It's saying unsupported hypervisor, configuration is likely broken, Please switch to supported graphics device to avoid problems.

You've provided on clues as to what Ubuntu product, or release of that product you're using, so we can't really comment on your actual Ubuntu as we don't know what that is. The error link you pasted shows likely problems with your HOST setup though.

This question is similar to: vmwgfx failure on Ubuntu boot. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
